# Функция срабатывает 1 раз

Tags: javascript, html5

У ModalCat прописан inline стиль `display="none"`, у блока Search прописано `onclick="closeModal()"` при нажатии на блок Search блок ModalCat появляется, после повторного нажатия исчезает, но потом после очередного нажатия уже он не появляется.

```
const ModalCat = document.querySelector(".modalCategories");
const Search = document.querySelector(".intro__search-category");


function closeModal() {
    Search.addEventListener('click', function() {
            ModalCat.style.display="block";
        });

    if (ModalCat.style.display="block") {
        Search.addEventListener('click', function() {
            ModalCat.style.display="none";
        })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы слишком накрутили в `closeModal`.

```
function closeModal() {
  ModalCat.style.display = ModalCat.style.display == "none"? "block" : "none";
}
```

*Совет дня: Добавлять обработчики событий в обработчиках событий - прямая дорога в ад.*

Comment: Спасибо, работает, не видел такой простой формы записи)